# Running time for algorithms that solve graph problems

Tags: performance, graph, complexity-theory

When people talk about algorithms to solve graph problems, which input is taken into account for the running time - the number of vertices, number of edges, both or either? Put differently, could `O(|V|)`, `O(|E|)` and `O(|V||E|)` all be valid polynomial running times for graphing algorithms? Does it matter if one of `|V|` or `|E|` is bigger than the other?

Comment: E varies depending on the exact graph and could be O(V) or O(V^2). Often times best algorithm choice is dependent on which E is closer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both may be relevant, depending on the algorithm. Only the input(s) that has a significant impact is used to compute the complexity.

You can have a look at his link for a few examples of complexity of known graph algorithms: http://bigocheatsheet.com/. You can see that sometimes either one of `|V|` or `|E|` appears, sometimes both.